# Parse Deploy failed with error:TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method '_extend'

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to deploy my code as I always do, nothing special:

`var Post = new Parse.Object.extend("Post");`

When I try to deploy my JS file as I've done about 2000 times or so before, I'm getting this error:

```
Deploy failed with error:TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method '_extend'
at new b.Object.extend (Parse.js:2:29356)
at triggers/post.js:1:12  <---- THIS IS THE LINE WITH THE CODE ABOVE
at main.js:3:1
```

There is nothing fancy/hacky about my project, and another JS file at the same folder with the same code ("_User" instead of "Post") works perfectly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me too and it got solved when I switched to a better internet connection!
Maybe my file is now taking too long to upload and something times out.

Comment: I've posted it to Google Groups of Parse and I've been told to remove the 'new' keyword, then it worked.